# How to avoid multiple error at same time in parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

How to avoid multiple error at same time in parsley.js? For example I want to validate the field with following condition email and require, min length ? but want to display one error at a time?

Comment: This can be done through a simple if - else if structure

Comment: Please share the idea  .. thank for your response

Answer (score 0):

probably this would be of some help.

https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/189

The basic idea was to get all messages in a list. Hide all and show only the one required out of it.